# There is a set of pairs (set_pairs) and I want to create a set (set_fsts) of first elements of those pairs. How can I do this in Isabelle?

Tags: set, isabelle, pairing, fst

There is a set of pairs (set_pairs) and I want to create a set (set_fsts) of first elements of those pairs. I am writing it in the following way

definition "set_fsts = {f . p ∈ set_piars  ∧ fst p = f}"
but Isabelle shows me this err msg: Extra variable on rhs "p"

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce p by existential quantification, i.e. EX p. P : set_pairs ...

Shorter way would be to define set_fsts as fst ` set_pairs

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the following piece of code but it is still not working. What am I missing?                                                                                               definition "set_pairs≡{(1,2), (3,4)}"
definition "set_fsts ≡ {fst p. ∀p ∈ set_pairs}"

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
set_fsts = {fst p . p ∈ set_piars}
```

This would work in Isabelle/ZF, I am not sure about Isabelle/HOL.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the following piece of code but it is still not working. What am I missing?                                                                                               definition "set_pairs≡{(1,2), (3,4)}"
definition "set_fsts ≡ {fst p. ∀p ∈ set_pairs}"

Comment: Did you try without the ∀ quantifier (as in my response)?